# Print new row after n divs

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I am struggling to find a solution for this problem:

```
<?php 
$counter = 1;
while (has_sub_field('company_members')) :  
    echo '<div class="row">';  
    while ($counter <= 3)  :
        get_template_part('team-member-box'); ++$counter;
    endwhile;
    echo '</div>'; 
    $counter = 1;
endwhile; 
?>
```

What I want the code to do is to print 3 "team-member-box" and then create a new row.

So far all the boxes have been collocated in one single row.

The code right now prints the same box for three times, instead I want it to take 3 elements in the repeater field "company_members" and print within a new row the next 3 elements.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: There is no need to use `<?php` and `?>` on each line, one enclosing the whole body would greatly improve readability. Also `while () { body; }` syntax would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you try to do but here is a general way to display list of data in 3 per row:

```
$counter = 0;

echo '<div class="row">';

while (has_sub_field('company_members')) {

    echo ($counter++ % 3 == 0) ? '</div><div class="row">' : '';

    get_template_part('team-member-box'); 

}

echo '</div>';
```

**Explained:**
[has_sub_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/has_sub_field/) it loops all company_members, I guess `get_template_part` renders some html using the current item. See `the_sub_field('content')` in the above link.

The `$counter` is not related to above behavior it is just used to separate the results in chunks of 3 and wrapping them in divs.

Comment: You don't need to reset the counter once you use modulo in your condition

Comment: <?php $counter = 0;
    echo '<div class="row">'; //open first row
    while (has_sub_field('company_members')) {  
      if($counter % 3 == 0){
         echo '</div><div class="row">'; //close old row and start new one
         $counter = 0;  //reset the counter
      } 
    get_template_part('team-member-box'); 
    $counter++;
    }
  echo '</div>'; //close last row ?>

This apparently is the solution.

I know it is related somehow to the counter and some array involved, however I don't understand the flow.
Could anyone please explain me it?

Comment: As far as I understand like in java the first element of the array by default is $array[0]. What should I do to change this behavior in order for this to be $array[i+1] the first element in this context?

Comment: Hello, I just spotted a problem with the code, an empty <div class="row"> </div> line is created at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this. And to fix the issue of creating an empty row at the beginning add this:

```
if($counter) :
  echo ($counter++ % 2 == 0) ? '</div><div class="row">' : '';
else :
  $counter++;
endif;
```